# Making Multi-Dimensional Array with string keys in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

This is kinda dumb question but after all these tries i get confused when i go too far...
I want a data like: `Name` `Price` `Owner` in different arrays as categories.
Like ie. i would like to access it via `$product['category']['name']['name']` or `$product['category']['name']['price']`.
However i would need to check in which categories there is key `['name']` as well.
Any examples would be nice to learn from ;)

Comment: can you let us know what you have tried so far? Some code sample will help.

Comment: its hard to say because whatever i would try is just a problem of finding all categories the keyname is in. Im more like looking for an idea of how to do it, not solution ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop array:

```
foreach($product['category'] as $cat) {
    if (isset($cat['name']) { //this is true if 'name' have value different than null
        continue; //cat have name
    }
}
```

Comment: but that way i couldn't have $product['category']['name']['price'] or im wrong?

Comment: you have $cat['name']['price'] $cat is $product['category']